# Tag merge request: book → books

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I think the tag [book](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book) should be merged into [books](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books), since they clearly mean the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for what :p

Comment: Thanks for @Anna's edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been completed, and this placeholder answer is here to be up-voted or accepted so it'll be taken off the [unanswered](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/unanswered) question list. :P